# Projection of line

Tags: conic-sections

Let PQ be the latus rectum of the parabola $y = 4x$ with vertex A. Minimum length of the projection of PQ onto a tangent drawn in portion of parabola $PAQ$
answer is $2\sqrt{2}$.

I have tried drawing the diagram but couldn't get the proper understanding of the problem. I tried approaching it with vectors.

Firstly, I made two vectors, dot them both and finally differentiate but couldn't get the answer (I have assume angle between them as $\theta$). Any hints on how to approach this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer is not dependent on $a$?

Comment: It will be $2 \sqrt 2 a$ for tangent at $A$

Comment: how did you arrive to the answer ??

Comment: Correction: tangent at $P$ or $Q$.

Comment: @HariShankar I am unable to understand the correction given

Comment: If tangent makes angle $\theta $ with $x-$ axis, it makes $ \dfrac{\pi}{2}- \theta$ with the Latus rectum. So projection will be $4a \sin \theta $. The angle is greatest at $P$ or $Q$

Comment: @HariShankar thank you for your help I have understood the problem and the hint